# Convert Computed Column to Persistent

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have an issue, I'm trying to alter some tables in my database by adding a datetimeoffset column with UTC DateTime Zone, this column has to be calculated depending on the date and hour that's been inserted.

This is my code right now:

```
DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(FECHA), MONTH(FECHA), DAY(FECHA), HORA , 0, 0, 0)  
AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ) PERSISTED
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> Computed column cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

Comment: IMO, when you are saving year, month etc value then apply `AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time'` logic. Or datetime column is very important why make it computed in first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AT TIME ZONE` is [nondeterministic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

> Since some information (such as timezone rules) is maintained outside of SQL Server and are subject to occasional change, the AT TIME ZONE function is classed as nondeterministic.

Because the time zone is dependent on the OS, if someone changes the time zone, then your data gets out of whack.

Comment: Thanks Greg, is there any workaround for this or should I modify all the ETLs that inserts and updates all the tables ? (I'm trying to avoid this because they are already in production environment)..

Comment: why do you need it persisted?

Comment: Because we're going to join tables from different countries and different time zones, and the data is joined by its date and also the hour... So the best way we occurred to join it, it's by UTC.

Comment: have you tried `datetimeoffset` instead?  don't know how well that would handle daylight savings time, but if it is not an issue, then it may work.

Comment: yes, in fact, the column I'm adding is `datetimeoffset`.

Comment: it would help if you posted the failing TSQL statement

Comment: `ALTER TABLE MEXICO.TEST_TABLE ADD FECHA_HORA_UTC_TEMP AS (
DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(FECHA), MONTH(FECHA), DAY(FECHA), HORA , 0, 0, 0)  
AT TIME ZONE 'Central America Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ) PERSISTED`... Note: **FECHA** and **HORA** are table columns.